# Classification with n-grams

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

I want to use a `sklearn` classifier using n-gram features. Furthermore, I want to do cross-validation to find the best order of the n-grams. However, I am a bit stuck on how I can fit all the pieces together.

For now, I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

text = ... # This is the input text. A list of strings
labels = ... # These are the labels of each sentence
# Find the optimal order of the ngrams by cross-validation
scores = pd.Series(index=range(1,6), dtype=float)
folds = KFold(n_splits=3)

for n in range(1,6):
    count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(n,n), stop_words='english')
    X = count_vect.fit_transform(text)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
    clf = MultinomialNB()
    score = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=folds, n_jobs=-1)
    scores.loc[n] = np.mean(score)

# Evaluate the classifier using the best order found
order = scores.idxmax()
count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(order,order), stop_words='english')
X = count_vect.fit_transform(text)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print('Accuracy is {}'.format(acc))
```

However, I feel like this is the wrong way to do it, since I create a train-test split in every loop.

If a do a train-test split beforehand and apply the `CountVectorizer` to both parts separately, than these parts have different `shape`s, which causes problems when using `clf.fit` and `clf.score`.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** If I try to build a vocabulary first, I still have to build several vocabularies, since the vocabulary for unigrams is different from that of bigrams, etc.

To give an example:

```
# unigram vocab
vocab = set()
for sentence in text:
    for word in sentence:
        if word not in vocab:
            vocab.add(word)
len(vocab) # 47291

# bigram vocab
vocab = set()
for sentence in text:
    bigrams = nltk.ngrams(sentence, 2)
    for bigram in bigrams:
        if bigram not in vocab:
            vocab.add(bigram)
len(vocab) # 326044
```

This again leads me to the same problem of needing to apply the `CountVectorizer` for every n-gram size.

Comment: Build the vocabulary first, from the training set. Nothing keeps you from putting both words and bigrams (and beyond) in the same dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `vocabulary` parameter first. In some way you have to provide the entire vocabulary, otherwise the dimensions can never match (obviously). If you do the train/test split first, there might be words in one set which are not present in the other and there you get your dimension mismatch.

[The documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) says:

> If you do not provide an a-priori dictionary and you do not use an analyzer that does some kind of feature selection then the number of features will be equal to the vocabulary size found by analyzing the data.

Further down you'll find a description for `vocabulary`.

> **vocabulary**: 
>   Mapping or iterable, optional
>   Either a Mapping (e.g., a dict) where keys are terms and values are indices in the feature matrix, or an iterable over terms. If not given, a vocabulary is determined from the input documents. Indices in the mapping should not be repeated and should not have any gap between 0 and the largest index.

Comment: Okay, so I do the following. I get a list of all words in `text`, this is the `vocab`. Then, I can do the train-test split using `text` and `labels`. Afterwards, I can do the `CountVectorizer` on these separate parts, while setting the `vocabulary` parameter to `vocab`. Correct?

Comment: @JNevens Yes, this should work. In the end your feature vector for each word in *n*-dimensional where *n* is the number of words in the entire corpus. Your model will be trained on *n* dimensional vectors which means you cannot change the number of dimensions somehow - how should your model classify an *m* dimensional model?

Comment: As stated in my question, I would like to try the classifier for different orders of n-grams. So, if I do the `CountVectorizer` with 1-grams or with 2-grams, these have again different vocabulary sizes, since the former has all words as vocab while the latter has all bigrams as vocab.

Comment: @JNevens I don't understand the problem. You either build two separate models where each works on 1-gram or 2-gram vocabularies accordingly or you build just _one_ model which works on a vocabulary of 1-gram and 2-gram tokens. You only have these two options here. If you want to encode _all_ n-grams, then you'll have to build such a vocabulary for your model.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I indeed got it to work using the vocabularies.

Comment: @JNevens No worries :)